# Cannot make outbound call using Twilio Client quickstart starter app

Tags: javascript, twilio

I followed the Twilio Client JS Quickstart and setup a local instance of the starter app, but cannot successfully make outbound calls using my trial number. Upon calling a verified number, I hear the demo message from the client and a single ring before the call ends, and my verified number never shows an incoming call. The browser client says the call was successful, but my browser console shows no errors and the Twilio console debugger only shows a Schema validation warning (12200). I enabled `Twilio.Device`'s debug setting - the log reads:

```
[Device] Setting up PStream
[WSTransport] Opening socket
[WSTransport] attempting to connect
[WSTransport] Socket opened
[PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
[Device] Stream is ready
Calling +17869735640...
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "completed"
[Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway
[Connection] Disconnecting...
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
```

The docs suggest I should be able to make this call with my trial account - have the trial functionality limits changed?

Comment: What is the code you are using to play the message and forward the call?

Comment: @philnash https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-node

Comment: What is the TwiML in the response to the request that received a schema validation warning in the console? An invalid schema can cause a call to not complete correctly.

Comment: @philnash
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial number="+12345678901" callerId="+12345678902"/>
</Response>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your TwiML, that you added in the comments, is indeed incorrect. There is no `number` attribute on `<Dial>`. You should either add the number as the content of the `<Dial>` or embed a `<Number>` within. Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="+1987654321">+1234567890</Dial>
<Response>
```

Comment: FYI https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-ruby works as intended out of the box, the node equivalent currently does not. Thx for the prompt response!

Comment: Oh yeah, that is weird. I didn't see they were setting it as an attribute rather than content. I'll get that fixed.